# How to scroll to a specific object using scrollTo() in ScrollView?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, scrollview

I render several sections and one of the sections is a ScrollView. This ScrollView is a horizontal days calendar and each item is a`renderRow()` that and has `View` `Text` and `Button` wrapped together within one `View`:

```
render()
{
    //..
    let day = this.renderDaysView();

    return(
        <View style={{ backgroundColor: 'white' }}>
            {day}
        </View>
    )
}

renderDaysView()
{
    let renderRow = (rowData, rowID) => {   
        return (
            <View key={rowID}>
                <TouchableOpacity ... >
                    <View ... >
                        <Text ... >{currentWeekDay}</Text>
                    </View>
                </TouchableOpacity>
            </View>
        );
    }

    return (
        <ScrollView ref={(scrollview) => this._daysScrollView = scrollview} horizontal= 'true'> 
        {
            this.state.Days.map((item, index) => renderRow(item, index) )
        }
        </ScrollView>
    }
}
```

Now, when the screen gets displayed, I would like todays day to be right in the middle of the screen.

Following the [**Docs**](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/scrollview.html#scrollto), `scrollTo()` can take an `object`:

> scrollTo( y? , **object** , x?, animated? )

Currently I am using this hack (which is missing one part) where I multiply the current day of month with a specific value:

```
componentWillUpdate(newProps: Object, newState: Object) {

    this._daysScrollView.scrollTo(
        {
            x:  // if first week, do nothin
                newProps.currentDate.getDate() < 6 ?
                    0
                :   // elseif if last week, scroll to scrollView width (missing)
                    newProps.currentDate.getDate() > 27 ? 
                        (newProps.currentDate.getDate() * 55 ) - ( 7 * 52) // TODO: should be scrollview width
                :   // else someday later, put in in the middle
                    (newProps.currentDate.getDate() - 4) * 55, 

            animated: true
        }
    )
}
```

So I either need to know the width of _daysScrollView, or jump to that object - 4 (to keep it in middle)

**If my object is a component, how can I jump to a specific object?** (For ex. if today is the 19th, go to index 19)

Or for my hack,

**How can I get the width of my `_daysScrollView`?**(`_daysScrellView.width`) did not work 
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use the scrollTo method you would have to get the x/y position of the element you wanted to scroll to. An easier solution might be something like this:

```
componentDidUpdate() {
    let location = window.location;
    let dayOfMonth = new Date.getDate();
    location.hash = `#${dayOfMonth}`;
}
```

The `new Date.getDate();` will return a number 1 - 31 depending on the day in the month. So if you set the id of each day in your calendar to a number corresponding to its day in the month. The above will scroll to it.

```
location.hash = `#${dayOfMonth}`;
```

will then scroll the document to the element with that id attribute.

Set the id of each day to the it's numerical position in the month and window.location.hash to route to the anchor of the day within the page.

EDIT: Try replacing your `componentWillUpdate()` method with this `componentDidUpdate`.

Comment: I'm talking about the id property of the dom element. i.e. `<div id="_this_is_an_id" />` If each day of the month has an id according to the following schema: july 1st id="1" july 2nd id="2" etc... then the provided method will do what you are after.

Comment: Did you declare dayOfMonth? This block of code just worked perfectly in a component I tested it in. And my mistake, that componentWillUpdate should be componentDidUpdate for this to work. Sorry! I just tested it in a working application and it performs as expected. Scrolls to the element with that id.

Comment: I did not declare `dayOfMonth` since I have it already as `this.state.currentDay` which is a `Date` object, and for some reason it did not work until I wrapped it again with a `new Date()`. Thanks!